# How to do ASP.NET Core 3.1 routing (Route, ActionName) localization?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I am developing an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC website that uses domain names to determine the culture for localization.

For example, all requests going to the domain `example.com` will have the `en-US` culture, whereas all requests going to the domain `example.org` will have the `de-DE` culture.

I modified my previously unlocalized website to use localization in views, etc.. I have utilized an own `RequestCultureProvider` implementation to set the culture based on the domain name. The result was the following:

- `https://example.com/Products/My-Application/Help` is using `en-US` as the culture and have English texts.
- `https://example.org/Products/My-Application/Help` is using `de-DE` as the culture and have German texts.

*Note: `Products` is the controller, `My-Application` the name of the application (URL slug from the database), and `Help` is the action within the `Products` controller. The URL structure is the actual structure I am using for my website.*

**However, I also want to translate the URL while relying on English only names in the actual source code (controller classes and action functions).**

For example, here is a dummy controller with a single action (breaking with the example URL above due to simplification).

```cs
[Controller]
[Route("/Products")]
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    [ActionName("EnglishName")]
    public IActionResult EnglishName()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

For this simplified example:

- URL examples:

  - English URL: `https://example.com/Products/EnglishName`
  - German URL: `https://example.org/Produkte/GermanName`
- In source code (for clarity reasons), the value of `Route` of the controller shall not be changed.
- In source code (for clarity reasons), the value of `ActionName` of the `EnglishName` action function shall not be changed.
- In source code (for clarity reasons), the function name of the action `EnglishName` shall not be changed.
- In routing context, the value of `Route` shall be "*/Produkte*" in the `de-DE` culture.
- In routing context, the value of `ActionName` of the `EnglishName` action shall be "*GermanName*" in the `de-DE` culture.
- All localizations shall be using the "usual way" (*.resx* files, like the stock localization for views etc.).

**How can I achieve this without manually building a dynamic routing table?**

Currently, I have no starting point. Search results for e.g. *ASP.NET Core route localization* just bring up answers for having the culture in the URL (except domain name), but this is not my use case. I tried to use variable names for the attributes, but of course this does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filip Woj has pointed out a solution in his [blog post](https://www.strathweb.com/2019/08/dynamic-controller-routing-in-asp-net-core-3-0/).

He shows the usage of `MapDynamicControllerRoute` in combination with `DynamicRouteValueTransformer` class to translate the routes.